# Check if elements occur together in all lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Say I have a list of lists like so:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4,3,7,2],[4,3,2,9],[6,7],[5,1,0],[6,3,2,7]]
```

How would I write python code to check if there are elements that always occur together? For example, in the above example 2,3 and 6,7 always occur in the same lists. (there may be others, not sure).

What's the easiest to understand way of achieving this?

My only idea is to convert `inner-list1` to set and check intersection with `inner-list2` but when I check intersection with `inner-list3`, those elements may not occur at all in `inner-list3`.

Could I do something like:

```
for i in range(0,len(lists)):    
    a=set(lists[i]).intersection(lists[i+1])
    if (len(a))==0:
        continue
    else:
        a.intersection(lists[i+1])
```

This of course doesn't work but how could I formally code this or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: For 2-combos, it is easy, but the problem is harder if you for instance look whether `3` always occurs together with `1` and `2`.

Comment: Are the `elements` of the `lists` always `integers` from `1-9`?

Comment: Yes, always integers from 1 to 9 and 2 or more may occur together like @WillemVanOnsem said. Although ideally I'd like to have a solution that would work for any integers, not just 1 to 9.

Answer (score 5):

#### Using `itertools.combinations`:

I initially thought of using something with [`itertools.combination`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), <s>but as this allows `elements` from a `list` which are not next to each other, it wasn't going to work for the solution I had in mind.</s>

Turns out that when looking at non-numerical input `lists`, `itertools.combinations` *is* necessary in both cases. I had been confused because I assumed the `groups` had to be `adjacent`.

The way I thought would work best for this would be to generate the possible `elements` that *could* work and then check each one of these with a `function` against the `list` of `sub-lists` - as opposed to doing some kind of combinatoric work on the `list` and going down that path.

So to check if a `list` of possible `elements` is 'valid' i.e. if all the `elements` only occur together, I used a simple `if` with a generator with the `all()` and `any()` built-in `functions` to do this part of the job.

Now this was working, there needed to be a way of generating the potential `elements` that could occur. I just did this with two nested `for-loops` - one `iterating` over the `width` of the `window`, and one `iterating` over where the `start` of the `window` is.

Then from here, we just check if that set of `elements` is `valid` and add it to another `list` if it is!

---

```
import itertools

def valid(p):
    for s in l:
        if any(e in s for e in p) and not all(e in s for e in p):
            return False
    return True

l = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4,3,7,2],[4,3,2,9],[6,7],[5,1,0],[6,3,2,7]]
els = list(set(b for a in l for b in a))
sol = []
for w in range(2,len(els)+1):
    for c in itertools.combinations(els, w):
        if valid(c):
            sol.append(c)
```

which gives `sol` as:

```
[(2, 3), (6, 7)]]
```

---

These `2` `nested for-loops` can actually be thrown together into a nice `one-liner` (not sure if others think it is Pythonic):

```
sol = [c for w in range(2, len(els)+1) for c in itertools.combinations(els, w) if valid(c)]
```

which works just the same but is simply shorter.

---

Due to popular demand (`@Arman`), I have updated the answer so that it should now work for other `elements` apart from `0-9`. This was done with the introduction of a unique `elements` `list` (`els`).

---

And some tests from `@thanasisp` with the same code from above:

```
l = [[1, 3, 5, 7],[1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

gives `sol` as:

```
[(1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7), (3, 5), (3, 7), (5, 7), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 7), (1, 5, 7), (3, 5, 7), (1, 3, 5, 7)]
```

and again with:

```
 l = [[1, 2, 3, 5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

gives:

```
 [(1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7), (3, 5), (3, 7), (5, 7), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 7), (1, 5, 7), (3, 5, 7), (1, 3, 5, 7)]
```

which I believe is correct as the `2` *shouldn't* be in any groups as all other `elements` are in a different `sub-list`, so it can never make a group with another `element`.

Comment: How ever this will not work if integers be greater than 9.

Comment: @Arman True, but I made sure to ask the OP before I wrote the answer if that was fine...

Comment: _Although ideally I'd like to have a solution that would work for any integers, not just 1 to 9_ OP said.

Comment: That's right , how ever I my self always try to answer questions in general situation and do not limit my answer in OP question conditions , because this question will be seen many times in future and solution must answer questions similar to this.

Comment: @Arman I will see if I can improve my solution so the logic stays the same, but it is not limited from `1-9`...

Comment: It seems working only for combos with consecutive integers. For example if input list is `[[1,3,5,7],[1,3,5,7]]` result in variable `sol` is `[8,9]`. Could you test this input too?

Comment: @thanasisp Sorry, you were `100%` right, the code wasn't working as it should be as I was not considering the cases where the `elements` weren't `adjacent`... I have updated to use `itertools.combinations` now

Comment: After this revision https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47240853/6 it worked for previous example. But now test this `[[1,2,3,5,7], [1,3,5,7]]`, i think it's missing the 2 if that helps.

Comment: @thanasisp I have updated the answer with that test and I think it is fine.

Comment: yes it is, sorry. Add `[1,2]` to the last two lists and test please.

Comment: @thanasisp Adding `[1, 2]`  has the intended effect of removing all groups with `1` from the `sol` `list`. So making it:  `[(3, 5), (3, 7), (5, 7), (3, 5, 7)]`

Answer (score 3):

An other linear solution with default dicts (tuple is there to make hashable keys) :

```
from collections import defaultdict
isin,contains = defaultdict(list),defaultdict(list)

for i,s in enumerate(l):
    for k in s : 
        isin[k].append(i)

# isin is  {1: [0, 4], 2: [0, 1, 2, 5], 3: [0, 1, 2, 5], 6: [1, 3, 5],
# 5: [1, 4], 4: [1, 2], 7: [1, 3, 5], 9: [2], 0: [4]}
# element 1 is in sets numbered 0 and 4, and so on.

for k,ss in isin.items(): 
    contains[tuple(ss)].append(k)

# contains is  {(0, 4): [1], (0, 1, 2, 5): [2, 3], (1, 3, 5): [6, 7],
# (1, 4): [5], (1, 2): [4], (2,): [9], (4,): [0]})
# sets 0 and 4  contains 1, and no other contain 1.
```

Now if you look for elements which appear by group of `n`  (`n=2` here), type :

```
print ([p for p in contains.values() if len(p)==n])    
# [[2, 3], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: Nice. You can change the condition to `len(p) >= 2` though to make it more general.

Comment: Yes, just change len(p)==x for x elements .

Comment: I don't  think so. first loop do N append exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using set intersections, and it also works nicely for 3 or more elements per group: Note that I added an `8` to the `6,7` group.

```
lists = [[1,2,3], [6,5,4,3,7,2,8], [4,3,2,9], [8,6,7], [5,1,0], [6,3,8,2,7]]
```

First, we map each element to sets of all the other elements it appears together with:

```
groups = {}
for lst in lists:
    for x in lst:
        if x not in groups:
            groups[x] = set(lst)
        else:
            groups[x].intersection_update(lst)
# {0: {0, 1, 5}, 1: {1}, 2: {2, 3}, 3: {2, 3}, 4: {2, 3, 4}, 5: {5}, 
#  6: {8, 6, 7}, 7: {8, 6, 7}, 8: {8, 6, 7}, 9: {9, 2, 3, 4}}
```

Next, we retain only those elements where the relationship is bidirectional:

```
groups2 = {k: {v for v in groups[k] if k in groups[v]} for k in groups}
# {0: {0}, 1: {1}, 2: {2, 3}, 3: {2, 3}, 4: {4}, 5: {5}, 
#  6: {8, 6, 7}, 7: {8, 6, 7}, 8: {8, 6, 7}, 9: {9}}
```

Finally, we get the unique groups with more than one element:

```
groups3 = {frozenset(v) for v in groups2.values() if len(v) > 1}
# {frozenset({8, 6, 7}), frozenset({2, 3})}
```

Comment: can I say sorry?

Answer (score 3):

First, the data

```
data = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4,3,7,2],[4,3,2,9],[6,7],[5,1,0],[6,3,2,7]]
```

Generating combinations is expensive, so I wanted to avoid that as much as possible.

My "Eureka!" moment came when I realized I don't have to generate all the pairs. Instead, I can map each number to all the lists that contain it.

```
appears_in = defaultdict(set)
for g in groups:
    for number in g:
        appears_in[number].add(tuple(g))
```

The resulting dictionary is

```
{0: {(5, 1, 0)},
 1: {(5, 1, 0), (1, 2, 3)},
 2: {(4, 3, 2, 9), (6, 3, 2, 7), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2), (1, 2, 3)},
 3: {(4, 3, 2, 9), (6, 3, 2, 7), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2), (1, 2, 3)},
 4: {(4, 3, 2, 9), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2)},
 5: {(5, 1, 0), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2)},
 6: {(6, 3, 2, 7), (6, 7), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2)},
 7: {(6, 3, 2, 7), (6, 7), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2)},
 9: {(4, 3, 2, 9)}}
```

Look at the entries for 2 and 3

```
2: {(4, 3, 2, 9), (6, 3, 2, 7), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2), (1, 2, 3)},
3: {(4, 3, 2, 9), (6, 3, 2, 7), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2), (1, 2, 3)},
```

The set of lists containing 2 is identical to the set of lists containing 3. So I conclude that 2 and 3 always appear together.

Contrast this with 3 and 4

```
 3: {(4, 3, 2, 9), (6, 3, 2, 7), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2), (1, 2, 3)},
 4: {(4, 3, 2, 9),               (6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2)},
```

Notice the gaps where `(6, 3, 2, 7)` and `(1, 2, 3)` should be. I conclude that 3 and 4 do NOT always appear together.

Here is the complete code

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
from pprint import pprint

def always_appear_together(groups):
    appears_in = defaultdict(set)
    for g in groups:
        for number in g:
            appears_in[number].add(tuple(g))
    #pprint(appears_in)    # for debugging                                                                                                                        
    return [
        (i,j) 
        for (i,val_i),(j,val_j) in combinations(appears_in.items(),2) 
        if val_i == val_j
    ]
```

Running this gives

```
print(always_appear_together(data))
[(2, 3), (6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is brute force option that comes in my mind now, `dct` is counter dictionary for each digit , then we check for same lists in `dct` that means both digit occurs in same list indexes:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4,3,7,2,1],[4,3,2,9,1],[6,7],[5,1,2,3,0],[6,3,2,7,1]]
dct = defaultdict(list)
for i, v in enumerate(l):
    for x in v:
        dct[x].append(i)

dct # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [4], 1: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5], 2: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5], 3: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5], 4: [1, 2], 5: [1, 4], 6: [1, 3, 5], 7: [1, 3, 5], 9: [2]})
new_d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in dct.items():
    for k2, v2 in dct.items():
        if(v == v2) and k != k2):
            new_d[k].append(k2)
new_d # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2], 6: [7], 7: [6]})
```

also it is a very expensive operation , it's `O(N*N*M)` : `N = list elements` and `M = longest sublist`

Comment: Can't you instantiate `dct` with sets (i.e. `dct = defaultdict(set)`) which means you don't need to do the set conversion later.

Comment: @Ben , you were right if there were an example that one digit appears in one list twice , because lists are in sorted order it doesn't even have to be cast to `set` ,I didn't notice that lists was sorted in `dct`, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution has a **linear** `O(n)` complexity where n is the total number of numbers in all lists (after flattening). The code is `Python2.x`

I'm using a bitmap representation (made easy with python's endless numbers) of all the possible patterns. For example if a number is present in `list0` and `list2` but not `list1`, the respective pattern will be `...000101`. For example in the given input, the value 2 will have the following bitmap pattern: `100111` and so will the value 3

```
l = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4,3,7,2],[4,3,2,9],[6,7],[5,1,0],[6,3,2,7]]

num_to_pattern = {}
for i, sublist in enumerate(l):
    for num in sublist:
        # turning ON the respective bit for each value
        if not num in num_to_pattern:
            num_to_pattern[num] = 1 << i
        else:
            num_to_pattern[num] |= (1 << i)

pattern_to_num_list = {}
# mapping patterns to all their respective numbers
for num, pattern in num_to_pattern.iteritems():
    if not pattern in pattern_to_num_list:
        pattern_to_num_list[pattern] = [num]
    else:
        pattern_to_num_list[pattern].append(num)

print pattern_to_num_list
```

This code will print:

```
{4: [9], 6: [4], 39: [2, 3], 42: [6, 7], 16: [0], 17: [1], 18: [5]}
```

And you can map and filter whichever sublists you'd like (in your case - lists equal or larger than 2):

```
print filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2, pattern_to_num_list.values())
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but IMHO the code could be made a lot shorter and easier to comprehens using `collections.defaultdict`, `|=` operator. and list comprehension.

Comment: Not linear. The k-bit operations you're doing take O(k) time each. The core problem is that a bitmask representation has to spend bits on all the zeros, so its size is proportional to the highest set bit instead of the number of set bits.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the easiest to understand way of achieving this?

I tried to make my solution as short as possible. I also worked to optimize it as much as I could. It works for **any integer** as you prefer.

Here is the code with a lot of comments that **explain** it, followed by **more** essential explanations:

Note: In the following code, I used `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4]]` as an example of the original list instead of the one in your question, to make explanation easier.

## Code

```py
import itertools

# The original list of lists
org_list = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4]]

# Sort the lists of org_list to ensure that the resulting tuples of
# itertools.combinations below are sorted also, because later, we 
# don't want (1, 2) to be not equal to (2, 1)
org_list = [sorted(l) for l in org_list]

# This list will contain the combinations of the original list
list_of_combinations = []

# --Building list_of_combinations--
# Looping through every list in the original list of lists (org_list)
for i, l in enumerate(org_list):
    # Create a new set to hold the combinations for the i-th list of org_list
    list_of_combinations.append(set())
    # Starting with 2 because we want the combination to contain two
    # items at least, and ending at len(org_list[i])+1 because we want
    # the maximum length of the combination to be equal to the length
    # of its original list
    for comb_length in range(2, len(l) + 1):
        # Update the set with its combinations of length comb_length
        list_of_combinations[i].update(
            tuple(itertools.combinations(org_list[i], comb_length))
        )

# Now list_of_combinations = [
#                               {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)},
#                               {(1, 2), (1, 2, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)}
#                           ]

# This will hold the result. In our case: [2, 3], and [6, 7]
# It is a set because we don't want the result to contain duplicate items
combs = set()

# Looping through the sets in list_of_combinations
for s in list_of_combinations:
    # s = {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)} for example
    # Looping through the combinations in the set s
    for comb in s:
        # comb = (1, 2) for example
        # Set a flag (f) initially to 1
        f = 1
        # Loop through the sets in list_of_combinations
        for ind, se in enumerate(list_of_combinations):
            # See if comb exists in the set se
            if comb not in se:
                # If not, see if any number in comb exists in the ind-th list of
                # the original list
                for n in comb:
                    if n in org_list[ind]:
                        # If so, set f to 0
                        f = 0
                        break
        # if f is still 1, then the current comb satisfy our conditions
        # so we add it to the result
        if f == 1:
            combs.add(comb)

print(combs)
```

Output:

```py
{(1, 2)}
```

as expected.

For the list in your question, the output of this code is `{(2, 3), (6, 7)}` which is as expected also.

### `itertools.combinations`?

`itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`: Returns `r` length tuples of elements from the input `iterable`. For example:

```py
list(itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2))
```

gives

```py
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

### Why using sets?

In the code above, you can notice that sets are used to hold the combinations of each list from the original list. This is because checking for membership of a value in a set is *very* fast, and we do a lot of such checks in the code.

## Explaining the main idea

Assume that our original list is `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4]]`.

1. Get the required set of combinations for each list in the original:

   For `[1, 2, 3]`: the set of combinations is `(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)`

   For `[2, 1, 4]`: the set of combinations is `(1, 2), (1, 2, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)`
2. For **each** of the combinations, and in order to be in the output of our code (meaning that it satisfies our condition), we want to make sure that for **each** set of combinations, **either**

   - it **exists** in this set (i.e. the items of this combination occur together in this set)
   - or it does **not** exist in this set -> **none** of its items should appear in the corresponding list

   #### For example

   Let's take `(1, 3)` from the *first* set of combinations. We iterate through the combination sets:

   For the *first* set, we can see that `(1, 3)` exists into it, so we move forward.

   For the *second* set, we can see that it does not exist into it, so we want to see if **any** of its items exists in the corresponding list (i.e the *second* list of the original list: `[2, 1, 4]`):

   Starting with `1`, we can see that it exists in the corresponding list -> `(1, 3)` can't be in the output because it does not satisfy the required condition.

Comment: @ammarx...I am sorry if my tone seemed rude or something. In given example, trying turning [6,7] to [6,7,3]...I may be wrong..

Comment: @ShihabShahriar No worries. But please, if you have a problem, please describe it clearly, and specify what you expect, and why, so we can work toward solving it; I don't understand what you mean by "trying turning `[6,7]` to `[6,7,3]`".

Comment: @ShihabShahriar If you add `3` to `[6,7]`, 3 does still not always appear together with 6 and 7 (it also appears in lists that do not have 6 or 7), and neither does it always appear together with 2 anymore (no 2 in `[3,6,7]`).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a brute-force solution, however, it will generate a large list of all elements that occur together by generating permutations of every sublist in `l` and filtering to find any permutations whose elements of which all appear in a sublist of `l`. If any permutations pass that condition, the permutation will be added to `final_pairs`:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4,3,7,2],[4,3,2,9],[6,7],[5,1,0],[6,3,2,7]]
import itertools
final_pairs = []
for i in l:
    combos = [list(itertools.permutations(i, b)) for b in range(2, len(i))]
    for combo in combos:
         for b in combo:
            if any(all(c in a for c in b) for a in l):
                final_pairs.append(combo)

final_data = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(final_pairs)))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 5, 6, 7, 3), (7, 3), (2, 6, 3, 7), (5, 3, 2, 6, 7), (5, 6, 4, 7), (7, 2, 5, 4, 6), (6, 7, 3, 4), (5, 2, 3, 7, 6), (7, 4, 3, 2), (6, 4, 7, 2), (4, 7, 6), (7, 3, 4, 6, 2), (5, 3, 7, 2, 6), (5, 7, 6, 4), (7, 4, 6, 2, 5), (7, 5, 4, 6, 3), (4, 2, 7, 3, 5), (4, 7, 3, 2), (2, 5, 4, 7, 3), (6, 5, 7, 2, 4), (4, 6, 7, 2), (2, 7, 5, 6, 3), (2, 6, 7), (5, 4, 2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 4, 6, 5), (5, 7, 2, 3), (3, 2, 4, 7, 6), (2, 6, 3, 5, 7), (3, 6, 5, 4, 7), (6, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6, 7, 5), (4, 3, 5, 2), (2, 3, 5, 7), (4, 5, 7, 3), (4, 6, 7, 2, 5), (3, 4, 5, 7, 2), (2, 4, 5, 6, 3), (3, 5, 2, 7, 6), (6, 3, 5, 7, 2), (5, 2, 7, 3, 6), (6, 3, 5, 4, 2), (2, 7, 4, 5), (2, 5, 3), (3, 2), (3, 2, 6, 7), (5, 3, 7, 6, 4), (4, 5), (2, 7, 3, 6, 4), (6, 4, 2, 5), (7, 5, 4, 2, 6), (2, 4, 3, 7, 6), (3, 2, 6), (4, 5, 3, 6), (7, 4, 3, 6, 5), (7, 3, 4), (5, 3, 4, 6, 7), (6, 5, 3, 2, 4), (6, 4, 2, 3), (5, 2, 7, 6, 3), (5, 4, 6, 3, 7), (3, 2, 6, 5, 7), (6, 5, 4, 3, 7), (3, 5, 2, 6, 4), (7, 3, 6, 2, 5), (2, 3, 7, 6, 4), (3, 4, 5, 2, 7), (7, 3, 5, 2), (2, 4, 5, 7), (2, 3, 6, 4), (7, 5, 6, 4), (7, 6, 2), (3, 9, 4), (4, 6, 5), (6, 4, 5, 3, 2), (6, 7, 3, 2, 5), (3, 5, 7, 6), (2, 5, 3, 4, 6), (5, 3, 6), (2, 3, 4, 6, 7), (6, 5, 2, 3, 7), (6, 3, 5, 2, 4), (5, 4, 2, 3), (5, 7, 6, 3, 2), (4, 6, 5, 2, 7), (7, 5, 2, 3), (4, 5, 2, 6, 3), (5, 7, 6, 3), (2, 7, 3, 4, 6), (2, 3, 6), (7, 4, 3, 5), (4, 3, 5, 6, 7), (7, 3, 6, 5, 2), (6, 2, 5, 3, 7), (5, 6, 4), (5, 2, 7, 6), (4, 6, 2, 3), (4, 3, 2, 6, 7), (3, 2, 7, 5), (6, 7, 2, 4, 5), (4, 3, 6, 2), (4, 3, 6, 7, 2), (6, 7, 4, 3, 2), (5, 1), (5, 7, 4, 3, 2), (6, 3, 7), (6, 7, 3, 4, 2), (7, 6, 3, 5, 2), (4, 9, 3), (4, 7, 5, 2), (5, 4, 2, 7, 6), (5, 3, 7, 2, 4), (3, 2, 5, 4, 7), (4, 2, 5, 7, 6), (3, 7, 6, 4), (7, 3, 2, 6, 4), (7, 2, 5, 3, 6), (2, 3, 5, 6, 4), (4, 5, 2, 3, 6), (5, 6, 7, 4, 3), (4, 2, 6, 5, 7), (6, 2, 3, 7), (7, 4, 5, 3), (5, 3, 4, 2, 7), (5, 7, 3), (5, 7, 3, 2, 6), (3, 5, 2, 7), (2, 7, 6, 5, 4), (4, 6, 5, 7), (3, 4, 7, 6, 5), (6, 2, 3, 5, 7), (6, 5, 3, 4, 2), (5, 4, 7, 2), (5, 7, 4, 6), (7, 6, 2, 5), (3, 4, 9), (6, 4, 5, 7, 2), (4, 7, 5, 3, 2), (3, 5, 6, 2), (4, 7, 2, 6, 3), (5, 4, 7), (5, 3, 7, 6, 2), (2, 4, 3, 5, 7), (1, 0), (3, 2, 6, 7, 5), (2, 3, 4, 7, 6), (6, 5, 2, 7), (7, 5, 2, 4, 3), (5, 3, 6, 2, 4), (2, 7), (2, 3, 6, 5, 7), (5, 3, 2, 6), (2, 6, 3, 4, 5), (6, 3, 7, 4, 5), (5, 6, 4, 2, 3), (2, 6, 5, 3, 4), (3, 4, 2, 7, 5), (5, 7, 3, 6, 4), (6, 3, 4, 5), (7, 4), (6, 7, 5), (7, 4, 6, 2), (6, 4, 3, 2, 7), (3, 5, 6), (3, 5, 6, 4, 2), (7, 2, 4), (2, 3, 6, 4, 5), (4, 2, 3), (2, 5, 3, 4, 7), (5, 2, 3, 6, 7), (4, 7, 6, 2), (3, 4, 6), (4, 3, 7, 6, 5), (7, 2, 4, 6, 5), (5, 3, 6, 7), (4, 6, 2, 5, 7), (6, 4, 3, 7, 2), (7, 4, 5, 2, 6), (3, 6, 7, 4, 5), (3, 6, 2, 5, 7), (3, 6, 2, 5), (5, 3, 4, 2, 6), (6, 5, 4, 3), (7, 4, 2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5, 6, 7), (3, 7, 4, 5, 2), (2, 4, 7, 5), (5, 7, 3, 4), (7, 5, 4, 6), (4, 7, 6, 5, 3), (4, 3, 2, 6, 5), (7, 6, 2, 4, 5), (6, 3, 4), (3, 4, 6, 2, 5), (2, 5, 4, 6, 3), (2, 6, 3, 7, 5), (6, 7, 2, 5, 4), (6, 5, 7, 3, 2), (4, 7, 3, 2, 6), (2, 6, 7, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5, 6), (3, 2, 5, 4), (5, 7, 6, 4, 2), (2, 4, 5, 7, 3), (7, 5, 4, 2, 3), (7, 6, 3, 5), (6, 5, 4), (3, 6, 5, 7, 4), (2, 7, 3, 6, 5), (4, 5, 2, 7), (7, 3, 5, 6, 4), (5, 7, 4, 2, 6), (7, 4, 3, 5, 6), (3, 4, 6, 2, 7), (2, 5, 4, 7), (2, 7, 6, 3, 4), (5, 7, 3, 2, 4), (2, 6, 7, 3), (3, 4, 2, 5), (3, 7, 2, 4, 6), (7, 6, 4, 2, 3), (3, 2, 7), (7, 6, 5, 2, 3), (7, 6, 4, 3), (5, 6, 3, 2, 4), (6, 5, 3, 4, 7), (9, 2, 4), (6, 7, 3, 5), (2, 3, 4, 7, 5), (7, 6, 4, 5), (6, 2, 5, 4), (5, 6, 7, 2, 4), (4, 6, 5, 7, 3), (4, 2, 3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 7, 3, 2), (4, 2, 6, 7), (6, 3, 4, 5, 7), (4, 7, 6, 2, 5), (7, 6, 3), (2, 6, 7, 3, 4), (6, 7, 3, 4, 5), (4, 6, 7, 5), (7, 5, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 3, 2), (5, 2, 6, 7), (3, 4), (7, 5, 3, 4, 6), (5, 7, 3, 6, 2), (7, 3, 6, 2, 4), (4, 7), (4, 5, 7, 6), (5, 6, 4, 2, 7), (3, 6, 7, 4), (5, 6), (7, 2, 5, 6, 4), (4, 5, 6, 7, 3), (2, 4, 3, 6, 5), (2, 3, 7), (7, 6, 3, 2, 4), (6, 4, 3, 5, 7), (6, 2, 7), (6, 3, 2, 7), (3, 5, 4, 6), (7, 6, 5, 4, 2), (6, 4, 7), (3, 7, 4, 2, 6), (3, 4, 2), (6, 2, 7, 5, 4), (2, 6, 5, 7, 3), (6, 2, 4, 5, 3), (4, 5, 3, 7), (4, 2, 6, 7, 3), (2, 4, 3), (4, 7, 3, 6, 5), (2, 4, 6, 3, 5), (6, 5, 7, 4, 3), (3, 7, 4, 6, 5), (7, 2, 4, 3, 6), (6, 7, 3, 2, 4), (6, 2, 7, 5, 3), (3, 4, 7, 2), (7, 4, 5, 6, 3), (2, 6, 5, 4, 7), (3, 6, 4, 7), (5, 7, 2), (2, 4, 5, 6), (2, 7, 4, 3, 6), (4, 5, 6, 2, 7), (5, 2, 3, 6), (4, 9, 2), (5, 4, 6, 7), (7, 3, 4, 6), (3, 2, 5, 7, 6), (7, 5, 4, 6, 2), (3, 7, 2, 5, 6), (3, 6, 5, 2, 4), (6, 4, 2, 3, 5), (6, 3, 2, 4, 7), (5, 4, 3, 7, 2), (5, 4, 3, 7, 6), (5, 7, 2, 4, 3), (3, 7, 2, 4), (4, 3, 2, 6), (4, 2, 6, 3, 5), (7, 4, 2, 6, 3), (4, 3, 6, 7), (2, 7, 5, 4), (5, 2, 4, 3, 7), (7, 3, 5, 4, 2), (3, 5, 2, 4, 6), (3, 2, 7, 6), (5, 7, 4, 6, 3), (9, 2, 3), (3, 2, 4, 5, 6), (2, 7, 5, 6, 4), (5, 3, 7, 6), (4, 7, 5, 3), (7, 3, 5, 2, 6), (6, 2, 7, 3), (7, 3, 4, 2, 5), (3, 7, 6, 5), (7, 2, 5), (5, 6, 2, 4), (7, 4, 5, 6), (2, 7, 6, 4, 3), (6, 2, 7, 5), (3, 6, 4, 7, 2), (2, 4, 3, 7, 5), (2, 6, 5, 7), (2, 5, 3, 6, 7), (3, 5, 2, 4), (1, 3), (4, 7, 3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 7, 3, 6), (2, 5), (2, 4, 7, 3, 5), (5, 4, 7, 3), (6, 5, 4, 2, 7), (5, 3, 2, 4, 7), (7, 3, 2, 6, 5), (7, 6, 2, 4), (5, 2, 3), (6, 7), (3, 6, 5, 7), (7, 6), (2, 7, 6, 3), (7, 5, 6, 2, 4), (4, 6, 2, 5, 3), (2, 6, 5), (6, 7, 5, 2), (3, 7, 5, 6), (6, 5, 2, 4, 7), (5, 4, 7, 2, 3), (5, 4, 3, 6), (4, 6, 2, 7, 5), (4, 2, 6, 7, 5), (5, 3, 2, 7), (5, 2, 4, 3), (7, 4, 6, 3, 2), (6, 4, 3, 2, 5), (3, 7, 4, 5, 6), (3, 7, 2), (7, 6, 3, 4, 2), (6, 2, 5, 7, 4), (2, 5, 4, 6, 7), (6, 3, 4, 2, 7), (7, 5, 2, 3, 6), (7, 6, 4, 5, 3), (5, 3, 6, 4, 7), (5, 3, 6, 2), (4, 7, 2, 5, 3), (4, 7, 6, 5), (4, 2, 7, 6), (7, 5, 6), (2, 6, 4, 5), (2, 4, 7, 6, 3), (3, 2, 4), (5, 3, 6, 4), (3, 7, 2, 5, 4), (7, 3, 6), (5, 3, 2, 7, 6), (2, 3, 7, 4, 5), (6, 3, 2, 5, 4), (2, 6, 4, 3), (3, 7, 6, 5, 2), (9, 4, 3), (6, 7, 2, 3, 5), (7, 4, 5, 3, 6), (3, 1), (2, 4, 5, 3, 6), (3, 6, 2, 4), (2, 5, 3, 4), (5, 2, 7, 3, 4), (4, 3, 6), (3, 2, 4, 6, 7), (3, 4, 5, 6), (5, 7, 3, 4, 6), (3, 6, 4, 5), (3, 4, 7, 5), (2, 4, 3, 5), (4, 6, 7), (5, 4, 3, 6, 2), (7, 3, 6, 4), (3, 2, 4, 6, 5), (4, 5, 6, 3), (4, 6, 7, 5, 2), (6, 7, 5, 2, 4), (6, 4, 7, 5, 3), (6, 5, 4, 2, 3), (4, 2, 3, 5, 7), (5, 6, 2, 7, 4), (4, 5, 2, 6), (6, 3, 5, 4), (7, 2, 5, 4, 3), (3, 6, 4, 2), (9, 4), (6, 2, 3, 5, 4), (4, 6, 5, 3, 2), (6, 3, 5, 2), (2, 5, 4, 6), (7, 6, 4, 3, 2), (7, 5, 3, 4, 2), (7, 4, 2, 5, 3), (2, 7, 3, 4), (5, 6, 2, 3, 7), (7, 2, 5, 6), (4, 3, 2, 7, 6), (5, 6, 4, 3), (4, 7, 6, 3, 5), (3, 4, 2, 7, 6), (2, 6, 7, 4), (2, 5, 7, 6, 4), (4, 3, 6, 5, 2), (2, 6, 3, 5), (7, 6, 4, 2), (4, 6, 7, 3, 2), (3, 6), (6, 7, 3, 2), (7, 2, 4, 6, 3), (6, 2, 5, 7), (3, 2, 5, 6, 7), (5, 7, 6, 2), (5, 6, 4, 3, 7), (6, 4, 3, 7, 5), (5, 4), (6, 5, 4, 3, 2), (7, 5, 6, 2, 3), (6, 2, 4, 5, 7), (7, 3, 5, 4, 6), (2, 6, 4, 3, 5), (3, 5, 2, 7, 4), (5, 3, 4, 7, 6), (2, 3, 4, 6), (4, 2, 5), (4, 6, 3, 5), (5, 3, 7, 4, 6), (6, 7, 5, 4, 3), (6, 4, 7, 3, 2), (4, 2, 5, 3, 6), (4, 5, 6), (5, 2, 6, 4, 7), (3, 6, 7, 5), (6, 3, 4, 2, 5), (6, 5, 7, 3, 4), (5, 6, 3, 4, 2), (3, 2, 6, 5, 4), (2, 5, 7, 4, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 7), (3, 5, 4, 7), (4, 2, 7, 3, 6), (5, 2, 4), (4, 5, 3, 2), (2, 7, 5, 3, 6), (4, 2, 5, 3), (6, 4, 2, 7), (2, 5, 4, 3, 7), (2, 5, 7, 6, 3), (3, 5, 4), (3, 2, 5, 7, 4), (7, 2, 6, 4, 5), (4, 3, 5, 7, 6), (3, 2, 6, 4, 5), (7, 6, 5, 4), (6, 2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 5, 3), (2, 7, 3), (2, 5, 6, 3, 7), (3, 7, 5), (6, 2), (6, 2, 4, 3), (5, 3, 4, 6), (7, 5, 6, 2), (3, 6, 2, 4, 7), (5, 2, 3, 7), (5, 4, 2, 6, 7), (5, 6, 2, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 7), (3, 5, 7, 4), (5, 4, 2, 7), (4, 6, 5, 2, 3), (4, 7, 5), (5, 4, 3, 2, 7), (2, 5, 6, 4, 3), (4, 6, 3, 7, 5), (6, 2, 4, 3, 7), (5, 2, 3, 4, 6), (7, 5, 3, 6, 2), (3, 7, 2, 5), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (5, 4, 2, 7, 3), (3, 2, 7, 6, 5), (2, 6, 4), (7, 4, 2), (7, 5, 3, 2, 4), (6, 2, 7, 3, 5), (5, 2, 7, 4), (4, 6, 2, 5), (7, 4, 3, 2, 6), (2, 4, 6, 5, 3), (4, 7, 5, 6), (2, 7, 5, 3), (7, 3, 6, 4, 5), (6, 5, 2), (2, 5, 7, 3, 6), (5, 3, 2, 6, 4), (3, 6, 7, 2, 4), (6, 4, 5, 3), (6, 2, 7, 4, 5), (6, 4, 5, 3, 7), (2, 3), (3, 6, 5, 4, 2), (2, 5, 6), (5, 6, 2, 3), (2, 3, 7, 6, 5), (6, 3, 2, 7, 4), (6, 5, 2, 4, 3), (6, 2, 7, 4), (6, 4, 2, 5, 7), (6, 5), (5, 6, 4, 3, 2), (6, 2, 3, 5), (4, 6, 5, 3), (4, 3, 5, 6, 2), (5, 4, 7, 6, 2), (5, 4, 7, 6), (7, 3, 2, 4, 5), (6, 5, 4, 7, 3), (4, 2, 3, 6, 7), (2, 5, 6, 4, 7), (3, 6, 5, 2), (6, 7, 4, 3, 5), (2, 3, 7, 6), (6, 3, 2), (4, 3, 7), (2, 5, 4, 7, 6), (3, 6, 5, 4), (3, 7, 2, 6), (2, 6, 5, 4, 3), (4, 2, 7, 5, 3), (6, 5, 2, 3), (6, 2, 3, 7, 4), (3, 5, 2, 6, 7), (5, 6, 2, 4, 7), (2, 7, 5, 3, 4), (6, 7, 5, 3), (2, 7, 3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3, 7), (7, 4, 6, 5, 2), (2, 5, 7, 3, 4), (3, 5, 7, 2, 6), (5, 3, 2, 4), (7, 5, 4, 3, 2), (6, 7, 5, 3, 2), (4, 3, 7, 6, 2), (2, 4, 6, 5, 7), (4, 3, 7, 2), (5, 7, 3, 4, 2), (6, 3, 4, 7), (5, 6, 7, 2), (6, 2, 5), (2, 6, 7, 5, 3), (5, 6, 7), (7, 4, 5, 2, 3), (5, 3, 6, 7, 4), (3, 6, 2, 7, 5), (2, 3, 6, 5, 4), (6, 4, 7, 2, 3), (6, 3, 5, 7, 4), (7, 2, 6, 5, 3), (7, 4, 2, 3), (3, 2, 4, 7), (5, 4, 2), (4, 7, 2, 5), (2, 4, 5), (2, 5, 6, 7, 4), (5, 7, 2, 3, 6), (3, 6, 7), (4, 3, 5, 2, 6), (5, 7, 6, 2, 3), (4, 7, 2, 3), (6, 2, 4, 7, 3), (3, 4, 6, 5, 2), (5, 6, 3, 7, 4), (3, 6, 2, 7), (3, 5, 7, 6, 4), (2, 3, 6, 7, 4), (3, 2, 7, 5, 6), (3, 4, 5, 7), (7, 3, 4, 2, 6), (5, 7, 3, 2), (2, 3, 5, 6, 7), (4, 2, 7, 5, 6), (3, 5, 4, 6, 7), (7, 3, 6, 5), (3, 6, 2, 7, 4), (6, 5, 3, 7), (3, 6, 2, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6, 2), (4, 5, 3, 7, 2), (4, 5, 7), (7, 3, 4, 5, 2), (3, 5, 4, 2, 6), (5, 7, 6, 4, 3), (2, 5, 4, 3), (3, 7, 5, 6, 2), (7, 5, 2, 3, 4), (6, 5, 7, 2), (4, 7, 2), (3, 9), (3, 7, 4, 5), (6, 2, 4, 3, 5), (4, 3), (7, 4, 2, 5), (6, 4, 3, 2), (5, 6, 4, 7, 2), (5, 2), (4, 3, 9), (5, 6, 4, 2), (5, 2, 6, 4, 3), (5, 3, 6, 2, 7), (2, 5, 6, 4), (4, 7, 6, 2, 3), (2, 6, 3, 4), (7, 3, 5, 6), (7, 2, 3), (4, 7, 5, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5, 2, 6), (4, 2, 6, 3), (3, 5, 6, 7, 2), (4, 5, 6, 7, 2), (7, 4, 2, 6, 5), (2, 7, 4), (4, 2, 3, 7, 5), (3, 7, 4), (2, 4, 6, 5), (7, 4, 3, 2, 5), (4, 7, 3, 5), (6, 7, 4, 5, 2), (4, 3, 7, 2, 6), (3, 6, 5, 7, 2), (3, 5, 7, 2, 4), (2, 4, 6, 3), (7, 5, 3, 2), (4, 6, 3, 5, 7), (2, 3, 5, 4), (4, 3, 5, 7, 2), (3, 2, 7, 4, 5), (5, 7, 2, 6), (4, 2, 5, 7, 3), (4, 6, 3, 2), (2, 6, 5, 7, 4), (1, 5), (3, 5, 4, 2), (5, 2, 7, 6, 4), (4, 7, 3, 6, 2), (2, 6, 3), (7, 4, 3), (6, 3, 2, 5), (4, 2, 3, 6, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7, 4, 6), (2, 6, 5, 4), (5, 2, 7, 4, 6), (2, 7, 3, 5, 6), (4, 6, 3, 2, 7), (5, 7, 2, 3, 4), (7, 2, 6, 5), (2, 3, 7, 5, 6), (6, 5, 3), (6, 2, 4, 7, 5), (7, 5), (7, 2, 6, 3), (4, 3, 5, 2, 7), (2, 6, 4, 5, 7), (3, 5, 7, 6, 2), (5, 3, 2), (5, 6, 7, 4, 2), (2, 5, 7), (3, 5, 6, 2, 4), (3, 2, 7, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5, 4, 7), (2, 3, 6, 7), (7, 6, 5, 3, 4), (7, 6, 3, 2, 5), (4, 5, 2, 3, 7), (7, 5, 4), (6, 5, 7, 2, 3), (5, 4, 6, 3), (7, 3, 4, 2), (5, 3, 4, 7), (5, 4, 2, 3, 6), (7, 5, 6, 3), (5, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 9), (5, 4, 2, 6), (3, 4, 5), (4, 7, 2, 5, 6), (3, 6, 4, 5, 2), (3, 2, 6, 7, 4), (6, 4, 2, 5, 3), (2, 7, 4, 5, 3), (4, 5, 6, 2, 3), (4, 6, 5, 7, 2), (7, 5, 2, 6), (6, 4, 5, 7, 3), (6, 3, 7, 4), (5, 2, 7, 3), (2, 5, 3, 7, 6), (2, 1), (5, 2, 6, 3, 7), (2, 7, 5, 6), (7, 2, 3, 4), (2, 6, 4, 7, 5), (2, 3, 7, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5, 6, 7), (4, 6, 3, 5, 2), (4, 5, 6, 3, 7), (3, 6, 7, 4, 2), (7, 2), (5, 3, 7, 4), (2, 4, 7, 5, 6), (6, 4, 5, 2), (6, 2, 4), (4, 3, 6, 2, 7), (5, 6, 2, 4, 3), (4, 2, 5, 3, 7), (2, 4, 7, 3, 6), (2, 5, 6, 7), (7, 2, 5, 6, 3), (2, 6, 7, 4, 3), (2, 6, 5, 3), (2, 6, 5, 3, 7), (2, 5, 4, 3, 6), (4, 6, 7, 3, 5), (5, 2, 3, 6, 4), (5, 6, 7, 2, 3), (6, 5, 7, 4, 2), (6, 2, 3, 4), (5, 4, 3), (4, 6, 5, 2), (7, 2, 6, 4, 3), (6, 4, 3, 5, 2), (2, 7, 4, 6, 3), (3, 6, 4), (6, 3, 4, 7, 2), (7, 5, 2, 6, 4), (4, 5, 2, 7, 3), (3, 4, 2, 6, 5), (3, 4, 7, 2, 6), (4, 2, 5, 6, 7), (5, 3, 4, 6, 2), (3, 7, 5, 2, 6), (4, 7, 5, 6, 3), (4, 3, 7, 2, 5), (3, 6, 2, 5, 4), (6, 5, 3, 2, 7), (3, 4, 2, 6, 7), (3, 4, 6, 7, 2), (3, 7, 6, 2, 5), (3, 5, 2), (6, 3, 2, 4, 5), (6, 7, 4, 2, 3), (2, 3, 7, 5, 4), (3, 5), (4, 2, 7), (5, 2, 4, 7), (4, 5, 2, 7, 6), (4, 6), (2, 3, 7, 5), (7, 2, 4, 6), (5, 7), (3, 2, 5, 4, 6), (5, 4, 6, 3, 2), (4, 5, 7, 6, 2), (5, 2, 4, 7, 3), (5, 6, 7, 3), (4, 2, 3, 5), (7, 2, 4, 3), (4, 7, 3), (4, 7, 5, 2, 6), (7, 6, 2, 3), (5, 2, 6), (7, 2, 4, 5, 6), (2, 6, 3, 4, 7), (2, 5, 7, 3), (4, 3, 7, 5, 6), (6, 4, 5, 2, 3), (2, 6, 4, 7), (7, 4, 3, 5, 2), (7, 3, 2, 5), (5, 2, 7, 4, 3), (5, 2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 7, 2, 3, 6), (3, 7, 2, 6, 5), (3, 2, 6, 4, 7), (3, 4, 7, 5, 6), (5, 4, 3, 2), (2, 3, 6, 7, 5), (3, 4, 5, 2), (2, 5, 7, 4, 3), (2, 3, 4, 5), (2, 7, 5), (5, 4, 6, 2, 3), (3, 7, 2, 6, 4), (4, 3, 6, 2, 5), (2, 4, 7, 6), (3, 5, 6, 7), (2, 4, 3, 7), (2, 6, 7, 3, 5), (6, 2, 3, 4, 7), (6, 5, 3, 7, 2), (3, 5, 7, 4, 2), (3, 5, 6, 4), (3, 6, 4, 5, 7), (7, 6, 3, 2), (5, 7, 4, 6, 2), (7, 3, 4, 6, 5), (2, 7, 6, 5, 3), (2, 7, 6, 4, 5), (6, 7, 5, 4), (4, 3, 6, 5, 7), (2, 7, 6, 5), (3, 7, 5, 4), (2, 6, 3, 5, 4), (6, 5, 7, 3), (2, 7, 6, 4), (6, 7, 5, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 7, 5), (2, 9, 4), (3, 5, 7, 4, 6), (6, 4, 3, 5), (7, 6, 5, 4, 3), (3, 4, 7, 5, 2), (6, 5, 2, 3, 4), (7, 3, 2, 5, 6), (7, 2, 5, 4), (2, 4, 6, 7, 3), (3, 7, 5, 2, 4), (6, 4, 2, 7, 5), (6, 2, 5, 3), (3, 2, 7, 5, 4), (7, 6, 2, 4, 3), (2, 5, 4), (7, 3, 5, 2, 4), (2, 4, 6, 3, 7), (7, 4, 3, 6), (6, 5, 2, 7, 3), (4, 6, 7, 5, 3), (4, 7, 6, 5, 2), (0, 5), (7, 5, 3), (4, 7, 2, 6, 5), (7, 4, 2, 5, 6), (4, 7, 3, 6), (4, 7, 3, 2, 5), (5, 3, 6, 4, 2), (5, 3, 7, 4, 2), (5, 6, 3, 7, 2), (2, 4), (7, 5, 6, 4, 2), (2, 6, 4, 5, 3), (5, 2, 6, 4), (4, 6, 3, 7), (7, 3, 6, 4, 2), (6, 5, 4, 2), (4, 3, 5), (6, 3, 2, 5, 7), (3, 2, 5), (7, 3, 6, 5, 4), (4, 3, 5, 6), (2, 7, 4, 3), (2, 4, 3, 6, 7), (6, 7, 3, 5, 2), (2, 3, 6, 4, 7), (4, 5, 7, 6, 3), (3, 2, 6, 5), (6, 3, 2, 4), (4, 2, 5, 7), (4, 5, 3, 6, 7), (3, 5, 2, 4, 7), (5, 7, 6), (7, 2, 6, 4), (7, 4, 6, 3), (3, 2, 4, 5, 7), (2, 9, 3), (5, 6, 3, 2, 7), (5, 6, 7, 4), (7, 2, 6, 3, 4), (7, 6, 4, 2, 5), (6, 2, 3), (2, 6, 4, 7, 3), (6, 5, 2, 7, 4), (4, 2, 3, 7, 6), (6, 4, 3), (5, 2, 6, 3, 4), (5, 6, 2, 7, 3), (7, 6, 5, 2), (6, 2, 4, 7), (5, 3, 4, 2), (3, 7, 5, 6, 4), (5, 7, 2, 6, 4), (4, 3, 7, 6), (5, 4, 6, 2), (6, 3, 7, 4, 2), (9, 3), (2, 4, 7), (3, 5, 4, 2, 7), (3, 6, 5), (4, 2, 6, 5, 3), (7, 3, 4, 5, 6), (6, 7, 4, 5), (7, 3, 4, 5), (5, 3, 2, 7, 4), (3, 5, 7, 2), (9, 3, 4), (6, 7, 2, 5, 3), (3, 5, 6, 4, 7), (2, 5, 7, 4), (5, 4, 7, 3, 6), (6, 7, 4, 3), (4, 3, 2, 5), (3, 6, 4, 2, 5), (7, 4, 6, 5), (6, 3, 7, 5), (3, 7, 4, 2, 5), (6, 4, 7, 2, 5), (7, 3, 2, 5, 4), (4, 2, 6), (4, 2, 3, 6), (7, 2, 3, 5), (2, 7, 4, 5, 6), (4, 6, 2, 7), (2, 7, 6, 3, 5), (7, 4, 5, 3, 2), (2, 6, 3, 7, 4), (6, 4, 5, 7), (5, 3, 6, 7, 2), (7, 6, 2, 3, 4), (7, 4, 2, 3, 6), (3, 7, 6, 2), (5, 6, 2, 7), (5, 7, 6, 2, 4), (5, 2, 4, 6, 3), (4, 3, 6, 7, 5), (5, 4, 2, 6, 3), (5, 2, 7), (9, 4, 2), (2, 7, 4, 3, 5), (7, 2, 4, 3, 5), (4, 6, 3, 2, 5), (6, 3, 7, 2, 5), (6, 7, 2), (3, 7, 6, 4, 5), (4, 5, 3, 7, 6), (6, 3, 7, 2, 4), (7, 2, 3, 5, 4), (3, 7), (7, 6, 5, 3, 2), (4, 5, 3, 2, 6), (3, 7, 5, 4, 2), (5, 6, 4, 7, 3), (4, 5, 2, 6, 7), (2, 5, 3, 7, 4), (2, 7, 6), (5, 7, 4, 2), (7, 6, 3, 4), (3, 7, 6), (4, 3, 7, 5, 2), (5, 4, 7, 6, 3), (5, 2, 4, 3, 6), (6, 4, 2, 3, 7), (6, 4, 5, 2, 7), (7, 6, 5, 2, 4), (7, 3, 2, 4), (3, 6, 7, 5, 4), (2, 6, 7, 5, 4), (3, 2, 4, 6), (5, 2, 4, 6), (7, 5, 6, 4, 3), (7, 2, 3, 6, 4), (6, 3, 7, 5, 2), (6, 2, 7, 4, 3), (7, 2, 4, 5), (3, 6, 4, 2, 7), (5, 2, 4, 7, 6), (2, 7, 5, 4, 6), (7, 5, 2, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5, 7, 6), (7, 4, 5), (3, 5, 4, 7, 6), (2, 5, 7, 6), (3, 4, 6, 5, 7), (4, 2, 7, 5), (7, 6, 3, 5, 4), (6, 7, 2, 3), (4, 2, 7, 3), (7, 4, 6, 2, 3), (4, 6, 3), (7, 3, 2, 6), (2, 4, 5, 3, 7), (6, 7, 2, 5), (5, 6, 3, 7), (5, 3, 2, 4, 6), (5, 7, 2, 6, 3), (4, 7, 5, 6, 2), (3, 4, 5, 6, 2), (2, 4, 7, 3), (5, 7, 3, 6), (2, 5, 3, 7), (7, 5, 2), (4, 5, 7, 2, 3), (4, 6, 2, 7, 3), (6, 2, 5, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (7, 3, 2), (7, 5, 4, 2), (7, 5, 4, 3, 6), (5, 6, 2), (7, 5, 3, 2, 6), (3, 2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 7), (6, 3, 5, 2, 7), (3, 7, 4, 6, 2), (7, 4, 5, 6, 2), (7, 2, 3, 6, 5), (6, 3, 5), (4, 3, 2), (3, 4, 6, 7, 5), (6, 7, 4, 2, 5), (7, 6, 4), (4, 5, 2, 3), (6, 3, 5, 7), (7, 6, 4, 5, 2), (6, 4, 2, 7, 3), (6, 5, 7, 4), (2, 4, 5, 7, 6), (7, 2, 5, 3), (6, 2, 5, 4, 3), (4, 2, 7, 6, 3), (7, 2, 3, 5, 6), (6, 4, 7, 5), (4, 6, 2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 6, 2), (2, 5, 3, 6), (6, 7, 2, 3, 4), (4, 6, 3, 7, 2), (6, 4, 7, 3), (6, 2, 5, 4, 7), (7, 3, 5, 4), (3, 7, 6, 5, 4), (6, 4, 2), (4, 2, 6, 5), (4, 5, 3, 6, 2), (4, 5, 2), (6, 4), (7, 5, 2, 6, 3), (4, 7, 2, 3, 5), (3, 5, 6, 7, 4), (3, 7, 6, 2, 4), (2, 4, 6, 7), (4, 6, 7, 3), (7, 5, 3, 6), (2, 4, 6), (3, 6, 2), (6, 7, 5, 2, 3), (6, 4, 7, 5, 2), (4, 7, 3, 5, 2), (6, 5, 4, 7), (7, 2, 6, 5, 4), (5, 2, 6, 3), (3, 6, 7, 2), (6, 3, 4, 5, 2), (5, 7, 2, 4), (2, 3, 5, 7, 4), (4, 5, 7, 2), (6, 5, 3, 7, 4), (5, 2, 3, 4, 7), (4, 3, 5, 7), (3, 2, 4, 7, 5), (7, 6, 4, 3, 5), (3, 4, 2, 5, 6), (7, 2, 6), (2, 5, 3, 6, 4), (9, 2), (3, 2, 6, 4), (3, 2, 5, 6, 4), (4, 2, 5, 6), (6, 2, 3, 4, 5), (7, 5, 6, 3, 4), (3, 5, 4, 6, 2), (5, 4, 7, 3, 2), (3, 6, 5, 2, 7), (7, 6, 2, 5, 3), (2, 4, 3, 6), (2, 7, 3, 5, 4), (2, 7, 4, 6, 5), (5, 7, 4, 2, 3), (5, 4, 6, 7, 2), (4, 6, 5, 3, 7), (7, 2, 3, 4, 5), (7, 6, 5, 3), (3, 4, 7, 6), (6, 3, 2, 7, 5), (2, 3, 6, 5), (5, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5, 7, 6), (7, 2, 6, 3, 5), (6, 7, 3), (5, 4, 6, 2, 7), (6, 7, 5, 4, 2), (6, 4, 7, 3, 5), (7, 3, 2, 4, 6), (5, 2, 6, 7, 4), (4, 2, 9), (7, 6, 2, 5, 4), (2, 6, 4, 3, 7), (6, 7, 4, 2), (9, 3, 2), (4, 3, 6, 5), (2, 4, 7, 5, 3), (7, 5, 2, 4), (6, 3, 7, 2), (4, 2, 7, 6, 5), (6, 2, 3, 7, 5), (3, 2, 7, 4), (3, 7, 6, 4, 2), (4, 6, 2, 3, 7), (7, 2, 3, 6), (3, 7, 5, 4, 6), (5, 7, 2, 4, 6), (4, 3, 2, 5, 6), (5, 0), (7, 3, 5), (3, 6, 4, 7, 5), (2, 3, 7, 4), (5, 3, 7, 2), (4, 2, 5, 6, 3), (2, 5, 6, 3), (5, 2, 4, 6, 7), (4, 5, 7, 2, 6), (7, 4, 6), (3, 6, 7, 2, 5), (4, 3, 2, 5, 7), (5, 4, 3, 6, 7), (4, 2), (2, 4, 7, 6, 5), (7, 4, 5, 2), (5, 3), (4, 2, 6, 3, 7), (2, 4, 9), (3, 5, 2, 6), (3, 4, 2, 5, 7), (6, 3, 5, 4, 7), (4, 5, 3, 2, 7), (4, 6, 2), (0, 1), (7, 2, 3, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5, 4, 6), (5, 4, 3, 2, 6), (5, 3, 7), (4, 7, 6, 3, 2), (3, 5, 4, 7, 2), (3, 7, 4, 2), (3, 9, 2), (5, 7, 4, 3, 6), (4, 6, 7, 2, 3), (5, 2, 3, 7, 4), (7, 4, 6, 5, 3), (5, 7, 4, 3), (3, 6, 7, 5, 2), (3, 2, 7, 6, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 7, 5, 4, 3), (6, 2, 7, 3, 4), (3, 5, 6, 2, 7), (6, 5, 2, 4), (5, 6, 3), (7, 5, 6, 3, 2), (6, 4, 5), (7, 3, 5, 6, 2), (3, 2, 4, 5), (3, 7, 5, 2), (7, 2, 4, 5, 3), (5, 7, 6, 3, 4), (6, 3, 4, 2), (7, 6, 5), (4, 3, 7, 5), (1, 2), (5, 4, 7, 2, 6), (6, 7, 2, 4, 3), (2, 4, 3, 5, 6), (4, 9), (4, 2, 3, 7), (2, 9), (7, 2, 5, 3, 4), (4, 7, 6, 3), (7, 4, 2, 6), (5, 3, 4, 7, 2), (4, 7, 5, 3, 6), (5, 7, 4), (6, 3), (5, 4, 6, 7, 3), (6, 2, 5, 7, 3), (5, 6, 3, 2), (6, 5, 4, 7, 2), (4, 7, 2, 6), (3, 4, 2, 7), (6, 7, 2, 4), (5, 6, 3, 4), (7, 6, 2, 3, 5), (4, 5, 6, 3, 2), (5, 6, 3, 4, 7), (3, 2, 9), (5, 6, 7, 3, 4), (7, 5, 3, 6, 4), (4, 5, 3), (2, 3, 4, 7), (2, 7, 3, 6), (5, 4, 6), (7, 4, 3, 6, 2), (7, 3, 6, 2), (6, 5, 3, 4), (7, 5, 4, 3), (6, 7, 4, 5, 3), (3, 4, 7, 6, 2), (3, 2, 5, 7), (6, 5, 3, 2), (4, 5, 6, 7), (7, 4, 6, 3, 5), (3, 7, 2, 4, 5), (6, 7, 3, 5, 4), (6, 3, 4, 7, 5), (7, 6, 3, 4, 5), (2, 7, 3, 5), (6, 7, 4), (2, 5, 6, 3, 4), (3, 4, 7, 2, 5), (3, 5, 7), (3, 7, 4, 6), (6, 3, 7, 5, 4), (3, 4, 2, 6), (3, 4, 6, 5), (3, 4, 6, 7), (6, 4, 3, 7), (2, 6, 7, 5)]
```

Comment: How this output satisfies OP requested answer?